# In how many ways can a person buy $10$ biscuits if he decides to take at least one biscuit of each variety?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a bakery four types of biscuits are available. In how many ways a person can buy $10$ biscuits if he decides to take at east one biscuit of each variety?

Let the four types of biscuits be A, B, C, and D.

Let us say he bought $x_1$ of A,  $x_2$ of B, $x_3$ of C, and $x_4$ of D.

Then , $^{x2 +x3 +x4+x1 }C_{x_1} + ^{x2+x3+x4 }C_{x_2} \ldots + x_4C_{x_4}$.

Now, solution in my book tells me that this way of solving is wrong. I don’t understand where am I wrong. I have arranged the way to buy the quantities also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

First see [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/).

The equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10$, where each variable is a positive integer **bijects** to:

$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 6$, where each variable is a non-negative integer.

The **bijects** verb refers to the fact that it is easy to set up a bijection between the set of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ solutions and the set of $(y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4)$ solutions.

Comment: I am not getting the  meaning of bijection and how is it used here. Why is y1..+ y4=6?

Comment: @Sarabsrimt The bijection is that $y_k = (x_k - 1) ~:~ k \in \{1,2,3,4\}.$  Thus, $x_k$ is a positive integer $\iff y_k$ is a non-negative integer.  Further, it is clear from the bijection that for a given satisfying $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\leftrightarrow(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$ that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$ must be exactly $4$ greater than $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4$.  Similar situations are given in the reference that I cited.